# ListView with changing sub headers fixed on top

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to implement a list with sub headers that get fixed to the top of the list while you move down the list.. The same implementation as the GMAIL app when reading an email thread.. while the user moves down the list, the header of the email that's being read sticks to the top of the screen and only moves away by another sub header of the same type.

Any idea of how to start implementing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question does not conform to the expected format : stackoverflow.com/faq#questions . You should ask help to solve a real issue, not to point out some docs. Please, search by yourself and come back when you'll get stucked. However, you would find help on SO chat;

Comment: ok, I changed the last sentence of the question to ask for help, because I actually need someone to help me here because I don't know how to start implementing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:
http://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/scrolltricks

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I don't have clear solution to give you, since I'm not an android expert, but why not using HTML features, like http://www.quackit.com/css/codes/css_floating_menu.cfm  ?